# Get path from URI in android version 7.0 and above

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, filepath, android-image, android-sharing

I am stuck in sharing task. I want to share and receive multimedia from and to app like Whatsapp sharing feature, user can share images videos from any other app to his own app, i am successful in sharing but i cannot get path from the shared uri, the uri i am getting from share intent is below

content://com.whatsapp.provider.media/item/14

This is WhatsApp video share URI i want its real path. I have gone through different links but cannot get the solution if anyone know the solution then please tell me i am stuck.

Thanks in advance